# Does dart support operator overloading? (not to be confused with overriding)

Tags: dart

This sounds like an exact duplicate of: [Does dart support operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130472/does-dart-support-operator-overloading)
But the name is misleading, the question is about how to override existing operators (the `==` operator).

As far as I understand, overloading a function means having multiple implementations that vary only in their parameters, but not in the name of the function:

```
int max(int a, int b);
double max(double a, double b);
```

By contrast, overriding means rewriting an existing implementation. Since the original function is replaced, there are no name clashes. This is common in OOP where you extend a base class and override its methods.

The [docs](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#overridable-operators) say that there are overridable operators. So I see that you can implement custom operators. At the same time, dart does not support overloading methods. So, does dart support overloading operators?

Would it be possible to write the following code:

```
class Matrix{
  Matrix operator+(int b){//...};
  Matrix operator+(Matrix b({//...};
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function overloading in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49734608/function-overloading-in-dart)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've essentially answered your own question.

> there are overridable operators. So I see that you can implement custom operators. At the same time, dart does not support overloading methods. So, does dart support overloading operators?

The Dart language specification says:

> ### *10.1.1 Operators*
>
> *Operators are instance methods with special names.*

Dart does not support overloading methods (or functions), operators are equivalent to methods, ergo, Dart does not support operator overloading.

Answer (score 4):

Yep, you can definitely do that, but you'll need to check the type inside the single method since there can't be duplicate methods for one operator:

```
class Matrix {
  int num = 0;
  Matrix(this.num);
  Matrix operator+(dynamic b) {
    if(b is int) {
      return Matrix(this.num + b);  
    } else if(b is Matrix){
      return Matrix(this.num + b.num);
    } 
  }
}

void main() {
  print((Matrix(5) + 6).num);  

  print((Matrix(7) + Matrix(3)).num);
}
```

Comment: well technically speaking this is not overloading. It's still just one method definition, with a hacky switch inside. But this will actually be useful to me, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

After loading up dartpad, dart does NOT seem to support overloading operators:

```
class A{
  operator*(int b){
    print("mul int");
  }
  operator*(double b){
    print("mul double");
  }
}
```

Leads to an error message:

```
Error compiling to JavaScript:
main.dart:5:11:
Error: '*' is already declared in this scope.
  operator*(double b){
```

Comment: Want to add that there are some work going on for making union types in Dart which would allow to create a method to takes multiple types of arguments: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/4938 . It is still not method/operator overloading but I would say it would be a fine workaround.

Comment: thanks for the issue link. But that's not very encouraging, it's been opened for almost 8 years now. I would assume that this becomes a part of the sketched up support for pattern matching/destructuring. Which would be a huge language change. And currently they're still deep in nnbd. So I'd wager it will be at least a year before union types become supported.

Answer (score 0):

In `geometry.dart` there is the following lines :

```dart
  /// Unary negation operator.
  ///
  /// Returns an offset with the coordinates negated.
  ///
  /// If the [Offset] represents an arrow on a plane, this operator returns the
  /// same arrow but pointing in the reverse direction.
  Offset operator -() => Offset(-dx, -dy);

After some research it appears that `-` operator can be used with 0 or 1 parameter, which allows it to be defined twice.

  /// Binary subtraction operator.
  ///
  /// Returns an offset whose [dx] value is the left-hand-side operand's [dx]
  /// minus the right-hand-side operand's [dx] and whose [dy] value is the
  /// left-hand-side operand's [dy] minus the right-hand-side operand's [dy].
  ///
  /// See also [translate].
  Offset operator -(Offset other) => Offset(dx - other.dx, dy - other.dy);
```

This is only due to the fact that `-` operator can be defined with 0 or 1 parameters.